# Custom property on File instance not cloned when passing to web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, structured-clone

According to MDN, `File` objects can be passed to Web Workers and they are properly cloned using the structured cloning algorithm. So far, so good. And this works in all browsers I've tested:

```
// myFile comes from a form.
// webWorker is the WebWorker object.
webWorker(myFile);  // myFile appears as-is on the other side,
                    // only losing non-enumerable properties
                    // and functions, per the spec.
```

But this doesn't work:

```
// myFile comes from a form.
// webWorker is the WebWorker object.
myFile.customIdProperty = 'some string value';
webWorker(myFile);  // myFile appears on the other side,
                    // WITHOUT the 'customIdProperty' property.
```

Curiously enough, this WORKS:

```
// myFile is a custom object now.
// webWorker is the WebWorker object.
myFile = {};
myFile.customIdProperty = 'some string value';
webWorker(myFile);  // myFile appears on the other side,
                    // WITH the 'customIdProperty' property.
```

This occurs in recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, etc. so I don't think it'a browser problem.

Options:

1. I'm doing something wrong and that is causing that property to be lost when cloning the object.
2. When cloning a predefined object (like File) and not an object I've created, all custom properties I add get lost because the browser ignores non-standard object properties.
3. I don't understand the spec and it's obvious custom properties are not cloned when passing objects to Web Workers.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks in advance ;))

Comment: Sounds like case 2. Just wrap your file and custom value in an object.

Comment: Yep, Bergi, that's the only solution I can think of, since File object won't serialize my custom properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The File interface has its own [serialization steps](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file), which are not the ones of Javascript objects. So yes, your custom properties are lost because these steps don't include grabbing own properties.

> 1. Set serialized.[[SnapshotState]] to value’s snapshot state.
> 2. Set serialized.[[ByteSequence]] to value’s underlying byte sequence.
> 3. Set serialized.[[Name]] to the value of value’s name attribute.
> 4. Set serialized.[[LastModified]] to the value of value’s lastModified attribute.

Comment: THANKS A LOT, Kaiido, I was looking for that information and I could not find it. I'll just wrap the underlying File object and the few properties I need in my own class. Not what I wanted but it works, it's more or less orthodox and I can't think of a better way. Again, thanks.